# Cannot take screen capture from specific url with Phantom JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I want to take a screen capture but the page doesn't load completely. I tested other URLs without problems but with this URL I can't.
i using phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.
in under link you can see it:
http://www.irmood.com/twitter-1.png
i checked page.onError no error

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();
    webpage.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 800 };
    webpage.scrollPosition = { top: 0, left: 0 };
    webpage.open('https://www.bershka.com/tr/en/woman/shoes/view-all-c1010224033.html', function(status) {
      if (status === 'fail') {
        console.error('webpage did not open successfully');
        phantom.exit(1);
      }
      var i = 0,
          top,
          queryFn = function() {
            return document.body.scrollHeight;
          };
      setInterval(function() {
        var filename = 'twitter-' + (++i) + '.png';
        console.log('Writing ' + filename + '...');
        webpage.render(filename);
        top = webpage.evaluate(queryFn);
        console.log('[' + i + '] top = ' + top);
        webpage.scrollPosition = { top: top + 1, left: 0 };

        if (i >= 5) {
          phantom.exit();
        }

      }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: Screenshot won't load. Please use an image-sharing service like imgur.com.

Answer (score 0):

Some webpages like bershka.com load html blocks using XHR after DOM is loaded. Phantom captured the webpage on DOM load state and it missed the rest http requests because it didn't execute JS anymore.

In your code you take screenshots every 3secs. Do you see any change on twitter-[2~5].png images comparing to twitter-1.png?

Comment: same twitter-1.png